# Scalable and exchangeable image inside a container

Tags: css, image

I am trying to place a scalable image inside a header container so that the image gets bigger or smaller depending upon the size in which the page is viewed.  In addition to scaling, it is appropriate to render a completely different image beyond certain breakpoints so that the amount of detail corresponds with the size of the image.  I am not aware of whether `html` statements can be used to select among images to render based upon view size, so it seems that the image must be selected via `css`:

```
.banner_img {
    background-image: url(image1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    …
} 

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .banner_img { background-image: url(img/image2.png); } 
} 

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .banner_img { background-image: url(img/image3.png); } 
} 

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .banner_img { background-image: url(img/image4.png); } 
}
```

An advantage of using the `<img>` tag is that in setting the image width to correspond to the width of the container, the image height would scale related to the image width, and the container would expand to fit the height of the image (as long as other settings didn't prevent that).  In other words, if

1. the actual size of the image is 900px by 300px,
2. the container is 1000px wide, and
3. the css for the image specifies `width: 33%;`

then

1. the image would scale to 300px wide,
2. the image would scale to 100px high, and
3. the image height would (could) force the container to expand to fit
   the image

Can the same be done for a `<div>` tag?  In order to allow for alternating images, it seems that they need to be placed in a `<div>` in the `html`.  We can set the `<div>` width to `width: 33%;`, but scaling the width in that way doesn't force the height of its container to expand if it needs to.  Setting the height of the `<div>` can force the container to grow, but in order to do that we need to set the height as a percentage of the width of the `<div>`, rather than a fixed height or a percentage of the container as `css` allows.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you are talking about image responsiveness check the example  view below

http://output.jsbin.com/vocojavepu

the code is here
http://jsbin.com/vocojavepu/2/edit?html

here I have used img-responsive a bootstrap class and custom class

```
.responsive-img{
    width:100%;
}
```